# How to filter datetime from an interval of two dates in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm

I'd like to filter an interval of two dates in one datetime on django ORM

date_start = 2021-05-17

date_end = 2021-05-18

inspect_dt in database is datetime type, sample:

2021-05-17 06:56:59

2021-05-17 06:58:32

2021-05-18 06:58:37

2021-05-18 06:59:53

2021-05-18 07:00:25

I want to pass date_start and date_end, then filter it on inspect_dt

What i tried:

```
filteredDate= inspectionDate.objects.all().filter(
                               inspect_dt__gt = date_start, inspect_dt__lt = date_end)
    
filteredDate= inspectionDate.objects.all().filter(
                               inspect_dt__contains = (date_start, date_end))
    
filteredDate= inspectionDate.objects.all().filter(
                               inspect_dt__range = (date_start, date_end))
```

> both returns were empty: []

Comment: you do not need .all() part only objects.filter() is enough. I am not saying that this is the reason for the error, tho. It may be.

Comment: What catches my eye is that your boundaries are `date` instances, but the field is `datetime`. You could cast the `inspect_dt` value to a date in your query as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date - or convert the boundaries into `datetime` instances eg with `datetime.datetime.combine(date_end, time.max)` and `datetime.datetime.combine(date_start, time.min)`. Do remember to think about whether you want `gt` or `gte` and `lt` or `lte` for your comparisons though, especially if using `date` queries.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper you are correct, I did like that:                                         
 filteredDate= inspectionDate.objects.filter(
                               inspect_dt__date__range = (date_start, date_end))

Comment: @SırrıKırımlıoğlu thank you for adivice, the trick was converto to date __date__range

Comment: Anytime you ned. I am happy it is solved.